# How can I determine after how many minutes of inactivity, Mac automatically logs off without admin privileges?

Tags: terminal, login, system-settings, administrator, sudo

I cannot access the Advanced page under System Preferences → Security & Privacy to check or change the automatic logout settings. I don't think I can change this setting, and I tried using `sudo` in the terminal to change it without success.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist com.apple.autologout.AutoLogOutDelay -int 3600
```

I'd just like to know how long I can be away from the computer without being logged out. I am on a university Mac desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Without sudo privileges, you can't access that information, neither read nor write.